# Imports from external libraries in views

Tags: scala, dependencies, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to use classes from a dependant project in my views, but it seems the scala compiler isn't able to pick it up.
The project is a sibling of the play project:

```
workspace/lib
workspace/play-project
```

But I get an error when compiling the project:

```
@import lib.TheClass

Error:
[error] scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/views/html/index.template.scala:28: not found: value lib
[error]         _display_ {import lib.TheClass
```

How can I set up a project dependency for the scale compiler?

I found the following related SO questions, but they seem to talk about projects stored in central repositories:

- [Play 2.0 Framework external Model in Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316827/play-2-0-framework-external-model-in-template)
- [Dependency Management with Play 2.0 Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422173/dependency-management-with-play-2-0-applications)

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the dependency on the lib project in your sbt configuration. There is a [guide in the sbt wiki](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Multi-Project). First you declare your lib project.

```
lazy val lib = Project(id = "lib",
                       base="../lib/")
```

Then you define the main project and let it depend on the lib project.

```
lazy val play = Project(id = "play-app",
                        base = file(".")) dependsOn(lib)
```